# What is ACRA for standard Java?

Tags: java, android, crash, acra

There is a very good crash reporting thing for Android called ACRA (http://code.google.com/p/acra/). Are there any similar libraries for standard (as opposed to mobile) Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202345/automatic-java-error-reporting-systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never run across one. But I have used ACRA before. The way that it uploads its data to google spreadsheet is pretty straight forward. You can just create a form on your G-Docs with whatever columns you want and then in your code create an HTTP request out of the base URL + parameters

Here is how you can build the url string to upload to a form:

```
String url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey="+ YOUR_KEY+
                         "&entry.0.single="+URLEncoder.encode(val1)+
                         "&entry.1.single="+URLEncoder.encode(val2)+
                         "&entry.2.single="+URLEncoder.encode(val3)+
                         "&entry.3.single="+URLEncoder.encode(val4);
myReq.sendPost(url, "");
```

In this example myReq is an HttpRequest object. Unfortunately I can't find the page where I picked this up from. But if you search around for things like "input to google form pro grammatically" or similar you can probably find a few people posting more about it. You can add more or fewer columns if you like just keep the "entry.#" portion of the url incremental.